# Is it possible to render a confirmation box from a rails controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm completely new to rails and writing an application for my company that will help keep better track of the MeetUps each member of my company is attending.

I've created a simple CRUD app via `rails generate scaffold User...` and have also created a client to hook in to the MeetUp API (http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/). When someone is creating a new User in my application with just their First/Last name and MeetUp memberId, I'd like to hit the MeetUp API and ensure that the memberId they entered is both valid and the one they meant to enter. **Once this information is pulled back from the API, I'd like to display a confirmation box with some information on the account so they can verify, click "Ok" or "Cancel", which will then either create a new user or tell them to try another memberId.** Is this possible? Relevant code below (apologies about the formatting):

Create User (users_controller.rb)

`def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)`

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.hasMeetUpAccount   # Render confirmation here
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  else
    format.html { render :new, notice: 'No MeetUp account found for #{@user.meetupid}' }
  end
end
```

`end`

user.rb

`class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'HTTPClient'
    def hasMeetUpAccount
        return HTTPClient.hasMeetUpAccount(["member_id", self.meetupid])
    end
end`

HTTPClient class

`require 'httparty'
class HTTPClient
    include HTTParty`

```
def self.GetData(method, method_args)
    HTTParty.get("#{BASE_URI}/#{method}?#{method_args}")
end

def self.hasMeetUpAccount(*args)
    local_args = SetUpArgs(args)

    data = GetData("members", local_args)
    return data
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you are overcomplicating it, just have the confirm on the "create user" button. Then run the validations and return if invalid.

Comment: What you want is wizard behavior for creating your user. Have a look at e.g. the wicked gem: https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Comment: @DickieBoy - The only problem with that is that you could potentially enter your MemberId incorrectly and then pull back a valid account (but not your own).

Comment: @JonLaMarr It looks like vulnerability. What prevents me  from creation of new User in your application with not my MeetUp account ?

Comment: @rossmari - I definitely realize that, but if an internal company member accidentally creates an account with a different MeetUp account, then it's just going to skew the metrics that this app would offer, which is why I'm trying to add some help for them to verify that the MemberId they add is actually their own.

Comment: @JonLaMarr..did you tried the my answer.please let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this i understand that  you need to show confirm box if the users exists else do something else.
You can try this.

```
##create action
respond_to do |format|
  if @user.hasMeetUpAccount
     format.html
     format.js
  else
     format.html { render :new }
  end
end




##create.html.erb or any partial inside create.html.erb(_dialog.html.erb)


             <!--  your view logic   -->
            //get the account info from the controller and save it in this hidden field and use it in the js below to show name/any other info that you need 
           <input id="account_name"  type="hidden" value="<%= @account.name %>">


        <script type='text/javascript'>

                 //show the dialog on page load
                 $(function () {  

                 //method to show confirm box
                 function show_confirm_box(){
                 var account_name=$("#account_name").val();
                 if(confirm("Is"+account_name+" your account ?")){
                          ##run ajax or any other thing that you want to do
                    }else{
                        return false;
                    }
              }//method ends
              //call above function when page is loaded and when you have the account name after 3 seconds,you can also use lenght() to verify if account_name hidden element is not empty
              timeout = setTimeout('show_confirm_box()', 3000);
             //clear timeout
              clearTimeout(timeout);
               });

        </script>
```

Comment: What about executing this logic but having the page render a partial that contains the confirmation box?

Comment: @Jimi...For partial,,you can use.html.erb instead of js.erb..i havr updated my answer...give a try pls

Comment: @Jimi if it worked for you..i will appreciate if you can accept this answer :)

Comment: Sorry @Milind, you are going to have to ask the post owner. I can't mark his this answer as correct for him.

Comment: sorry @Jimi..i thought you are the owner :(

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. I decided not to invest the time to do this. The above doesn't solve what I was asking though. Basically, the sequence of events is this: User enters their meetupId, this is posted to the controller to check to ensure they have an account. I then wanted to pull back that account and display their name in a confirm box to make sure they had entered the correct meetupid. Your answer would display the "Are you sure?", but no other information. Probably could have just done it some other way if I thought about it more. I'll mark this as the answer though. Thanks!

Comment: @JonLaMarr...the above code can be customised as the way you need...you can use a hidden field and store the account_name and call this method in settimeout function after page loads ....this can solve your issue...

Comment: @JonLaMarr...i have updated my answer...hope its near to what you need :)