# Add a Data Confirm Dialogue Box in Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app where I want to warn people if they're creating a duplicate `author`.  I have a `before_action` filter set up for the `create` method that looks like this:

```
  def check_for_duplicates
    @duplicates = Author.where(first_name: @new_author.first_name, last_name: @new_author.last_name)
    if @duplicates.count != 0
      ## THE NEXT LINE IS WHAT I NEED TO FIGURE OUT ##
      data: {confirm: "You already have an author with this name.  Are you sure you want to create another one?"}
    end
  end
```

I currently get the following server error:

```
SyntaxError - syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_end
      data: {confirm: "You already have ...
          ^
/Users/lizbayardelle/Code/MMR/app/controllers/authors_controller.rb:80: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...irect_to authors_path, notice "Sorry, you don't have permiss...
...                              ^:
  app/controllers/authors_controller.rb:73:in `'
```

However, this is expected because I know this line isn't how you do it.  I can't do it via `link_to` because I have to check to see if it's a duplicate first.

I've checked other SO questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29676763/is-it-possible-to-render-a-confirmation-box-from-a-rails-controller)) and everything seems to involve a fairly complicated, on-page javascript solution.

Is there a neat way to do this inside the controller?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do if author duplicates? You need to render something to user, html page with redirect or json.

Comment: @RomanAlekseiev Ideally, I want to warn them that the author is a duplicate and give them a choice to either stop the action and continue on the page they were on (without reloading) or continue the author create action anyway.

Comment: Yes but you will have to write little bit of JS. Steps would be making the form submit as ajax compatible ( with remote ). If its a duplicate then use create.js.erb. Stringify the parameters (which you got on the first submit ) and save it in the hidden field and now on clicking yes, submit the form on same endpoint with a flag to bypass the duplicate check.

Answer (score 0):

`data-confirm` attributes are really just an easy way to use the event handlers that Rails UJS provides in javascript. You cannot trigger a confirm dialog from the back-end and the whole idea is just backwards.

As already suggested if you want to do this validation from the front end you need a route where you can find users by name and last_name. You don't even have to return JSON. Just do a HEAD request and check if the status is 200 OK or 302 FOUND or 404 NOT FOUND.

If you can't manage that you really want to handle this on the server side - just add a flag attribute and a custom validation to the model:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  # this creates an attribute without a db column.
  attribute :dup_warning_displayed, :boolean, default: false
  validate :name_duplication, unless: :dup_warning_displayed?, on: :create
  # ...

  def name_duplication
    if self.class.where(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name).any?
      errors.add(:base, "You already have an author with this name.  Are you sure you want to create another one?")
      dup_warning_displayed = true
    end
  end
end
```

You then need to pass the `dup_warning_displayed` attribute through the form:

```
<%= form_for(@author) do |f| %>
   # ...
   <%= f.hidden_field :dup_warning_displayed if @author.dup_warning_displayed? %>
   # ... 
<% end %>
```